# ActionBar with ViewPager - clicking partially visible tab crashes the app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I'm using a ViewPager to display 4 different fragments. I use the action bar to display the tabs for the navigation. It looks like that:

[image]

My problem is that initially 3 of the tabs are fully visible and the last one is partially visible. Clicking on any of the first 3 tabs is ok but when I click on the last one, the app crashes:

```
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.szymontrapp.englishverbs.DictionaryListFragment.onLoadFinished(DictionaryListFragment.java:200)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.szymontrapp.englishverbs.DictionaryListFragment.onLoadFinished(DictionaryListFragment.java:1)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:427)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:562)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.szymontrapp.englishverbs.DictionaryListFragment.onCreate(DictionaryListFragment.java:94)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1455)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:823)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:819)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.szymontrapp.englishverbs.DictionaryActivity$4.onTabSelected(DictionaryActivity.java:91)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplICS$TabWrapper.onTabSelected(ActionBarImplICS.java:454)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:587)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1084)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:532)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-06 13:35:01.825: E/AndroidRuntime(6676):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It seems that somehow the last fragment is not loaded initially. I'm using a custom class extending FragmentPageAdapter and GetItem method is called only for the first 3.

Should I try to force load all 4 fragments initially? Alternatively, how to handle loading of the last fragment properly?

There's quite a lot of code around the view pager and those fragments, I'm not sure how much code will be needed to answer my question. Let me know if I need to post the full code here.

Comment: How do you setup the Loader for the fragment for the partially visible tab?

Comment: Do you mean the loader for the list I have in each fragment? It's in onCreate in my Fragment's class.

Comment: Try to start the loader in the onActivityCreated() callback of the fragment(the one corresponding to the partially visible tab).

Comment: You gave me the idea - I moved it to onResume and it works too! Thanks a lot!

Comment: onActivityCreated() works well too.

How do I accept your answer? I can't as it's just a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the `Loader` in one of the callbacks(like `onActivityCreated()`) that run **after** the `onCreateView()` is called so you make sure that the `Loader` returning the data very fast doesn't put you in a position where the view of the `Fragment` is not yet created(the problem in your case).