# Swapping out Fragments fails with FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have the following...

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter code...

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private Fragment f;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Score"), ScoreFragment.class, null);
        f = new TeamFragment();
        this.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Team"), TeamFragment.class, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0){
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(context, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }
        else{
            return f;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0,
            android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0,
            android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /**
     * @return the f
     */
    public Fragment getF() {
        return f;
    }

    /**
     * @param f the f to set
     */
    public void setF(Fragment f) {
        startUpdate((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.pager));
        destroyItem((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.pager), 1, this.f);
        this.f = f;
        instantiateItem((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.pager), 1);
        finishUpdate((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.pager));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

However, when I call setF with a new fragment, the old one disappears as expected but the new one never shows up. Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

I tried changing to...

```
    public void setF(Fragment f) {
        ViewGroup g = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        startUpdate(g);
        destroyItem(g, 1, this.f);
        this.f = f;
        WebViewFragment v = (WebViewFragment)instantiateItem(g, 1);
        FragmentManager fm = v.getFragmentManager();
        finishUpdate(g);
        Fragment f3 = v;
        f3.setUserVisibleHint(true);
        setPrimaryItem(g,1,v);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

but now I get...

```
10-24 17:10:12.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 17:10:12.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:819)
10-24 17:10:12.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:152)
10-24 17:10:12.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
```

Looks like maybe a race condition?

[ActionBar with ViewPager - clicking partially visible tab crashes the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649540/actionbar-with-viewpager-clicking-partially-visible-tab-crashes-the-app)

*Update*

If I remove the setPrimaryItem(g,1,v); then it appears to run fine till I go to another tab and come back. Then it fails the same way. This leads me to believe I am doing it somewhat right and just missing something.

Comment: Could you please explain exactly by words what did you do? I have the same problem. Fragment never shows up. It's just a blank layout.

Comment: Been a while but give me a day or two to see if I can make it clearer

Comment: Thank you. I have figured it out. Looks the cause that causes my problem differs little bit from yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the functional version, I had to change multiple things around. I would still like to add to the BackStack (If you can do that you will get the check) but this should help anyone in the same boat.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments.add(new ScoreFragment());
        fragments.add(new TeamFragment());
        this.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Score"), ScoreFragment.class, null);
        this.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Team"), TeamFragment.class, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0,
            android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {}

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0,
            android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {}

    /**
     * @param f the f to set
     */
    public void setF(Fragment f) {
        int loc = actionBar.getSelectedTab().getPosition();
        fragments.set(loc, f);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof Fragment){
            if(fragments.contains(object))
                return POSITION_UNCHANGED;

        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to using transition fragment to replace, add or remove fragments might doesn’t word sometimes and it just shows a blank layout. This problem happen because some reasons. I had the problem and I figured it out. It just was the way that I implemented `onCreate` method in my fragmentActivity.

This is is how it was:

```
    protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.mybooks);
    }
```

And the problem was gone when I changed `android.os.Bundle` to just `Bundle`. I hope this help anybody who has same this problem.